# does a slight change in a real value cause a massive change from finite to infinite?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, dynamical-systems, abc-conjecture, arithmetic-dynamics

Can anybody give an example of a system of equivalence and/or inequality relations dependent to just a real value number like $\kappa$, which satisfies for **finitely** many integers if $\kappa =1$ and holds for **infinitely** many integers if we change $\kappa$ from $1$ by infinitely small real value like $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$.

an example like the statement of ABC conjecture below, but surely be much simpler to be resolved in an easy way.

---

If :

i) $\mathrm{rad}\,(n)$ *is the product of the distinct primes in* $n$,

ii) $A,B,C$ *are three positive coprime integers,*

iii) $A+B=C\ $,

iv) $\kappa \in \mathbb{R}$,

then for **infinitely** many exceptions we have: $$C<\mathrm{rad}\,(ABC)^{\kappa }\\ for\\ \kappa=1 
.\tag{1}$$ 
and if we change $\kappa$ infinitely small $\epsilon >0$ from $1$ upward then for **finitely** many exceptions we have: $$C<\mathrm{rad}\,(ABC)^{\kappa }\\ for\\ \kappa=1+ \epsilon 
.\tag{2}$$

---

I asked this question because it is somehow odd to me that a slight change in a real value parameter may cause a sudden change to the state of a system dependent to that value from $\aleph _0$ to finite!

Comment: Isn't your ABC example backwards? It has infinitely many exceptions if $\kappa=1$, but your question asks for a property that is satisfied for _finitely_ many integers if $\kappa=1$.

Comment: @TonyK does not change the generality of the question, it is enough to reverse the inequality mark and substitute infinite by finite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x$ be the set of numbers $x\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $1<x<\kappa$. Then for $\kappa=1$ there are **no** solutions, but for any $\kappa>1$ there are continuously infinite solutions!

If you want a set of solutions that are restricted to integers, consider the set of tuples $(x,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ with $1<x<\kappa^n$.

Edit: for a system where the number of solutions is finite but nonzero at $\kappa = 1$, take the following:

$x\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $1\leqslant x\leqslant\kappa^x$.

Then when $\kappa = 1$, there is exactly one solution, namely $x=1$. But if $\kappa > 1$, then for large enough $x$ it will always be true that $x<\kappa^x$, giving infinitely many solutions.

Comment: I'd bet that "finitely many solutions" was intended to exclude zero solutions, even though it wasn't explicitly stated.

Comment: Well done, can you give another example which instead of null solution for $\kappa=1$  in your second example ,there be finitely many solutions?

Comment: @MasM edited accordingly

Comment: Great, that implicitly implies how vast and mighty the real realm is, compare to countable world ;)